# Shorewall - Wildcard filter by source MAC address

Tags: shorewall

I currently have a Debian PC with two network interfaces acting as a router/gateway.

I have several cheap IP cameras that try to access external services, presumably for some kind of 'cloud' functionality. This functionality  cannot be disabled.

I'd like to add rules to Shorewall to drop outbound packets from these cameras to prevent them from accessing the internet. I have used a similar method to prevent secondhand consumer level VOIP devices from downloading unwanted configuration files in the past.

To achieve this, I could add filters by MAC address or IP for each camera. This is a bit tedious. e.g.

```
DROP local:~AA:BB:CC:11:22:33
DROP local:~AA:BB:CC:11:22:44
DROP local:~AA:BB:CC:11:22:55
etc..
```

Can I use some kind of wildcard? e.g.

```
DROP local:~AA:BB:CC:*
```

The cameras share a subnet with several other devices, and moving them to a new subnet just to apply firewall rules to them is not desirable.

Shorewall version is 5.0.15.6 on kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer wil be: No, you can't.

Shorewall has limited wildcard support for interface names (i.e. use 'ppp+'; that would match ppp0, ppp1, ppp2..etc.) and port names (http://shorewall.net/manpages/shorewall-interfaces.html) but not for mac address or ip address.

I have also done a quick test to get only "ERROR: Invalid MAC address....".

Comment: Thanks for the information.

I've ended up giving in and moving these devices to their own VLAN so that they can have their own Shorewall interface and zone. I then added a filter for this new zone so that they can't access the internet.

I was resistant to using VLANs in this case due to my lack of experience.

Comment: @toxicantidote, thats in any case a better solution.